# torch.Tensor manipulation - Comparing two vectors

Tags: vector, lua, torch

I've got two tensor objects repenting vectors:
    (0110010),
    (0111011)
I would like to compare between the two and create a new tensor vector:
    (0110010)
Iterating over them in a loop is very slow, I know there is a solution for this in Matlab so I assume there is one for tensors as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a logical and operation for tensors containing only 1 and 0 elements you could use the :cmul() member function (element-wise multiplication).

```
th> torch.Tensor({0,1,1,0,0,1,0}):cmul(torch.Tensor({0,1,1,1,0,1,1}))
 0
 1
 1
 0
 0
 1
 0
```

To compare two tensors element-wise you can use :eq():

```
th> torch.Tensor({0,1,1,0,0,1,0}):eq(torch.Tensor({0,1,1,1,0,1,1}))
 1
 1
 1
 0
 1
 1
 0
```